# Remove css cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp3 and I'm adapting a view that already had but I'm having confict with the stylesheet, cake.css and base.css automatically load and I move elements, not can erase it because I use it in the login and other views and I wonder if you can avoid carrying those stylesheets.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you should add your own style sheet that uses classes and/or ids present in this specific view to override the styles that you don't want from the default. For example, views that you bake have a div with the controller and action names as classes, so if this is the view for the user edit page for example, you could use `div.user.edit p { ... }` to target paragraph tags found only on that page.

If you put these rules in `webroot/css/custom.css`, you could load that file with `$this->Html->css('custom');`, either in your view or in `src/Template/Layout/default.ctp`. The latter option is my preference, since things like this tend to grow over time and you'll find yourself including this code in many views; using specific CSS selectors to target just this one page means that you can include it on every page this way without affecting the look of any others. And the CSS will be cached by browsers, meaning that you're not increasing network traffic noticeably by doing so.

You could presumably also exclude loading the default CSS by making changes to `src/Template/Layout/default.ctp`, but such changes tend to be hackish and fragile.